# PHP CURL in LOCAL vs Remote Server

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I have a question I can't understand....
I use CURL to this page.... 
**https://propiedades.com/alvaro-obregon-df/departamentos-renta**

My Code is this:

```
    $ch = curl_init($uri); // Init cURL session

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $uri); 

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

    $uagent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:22.0) Firefox/22.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/36.0.1985.125 Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $uagent);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.google.com');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true); 

    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);

    if (!is_null($postFields)) 
    { 
        $arr = explode("&", $postFields);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count(sizeof($arr)));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);
    }
    $info = curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close($ch);
```

In my Local host **$info Always HAS all HTML content**... in My Remote Server (where is the hosting of my web app)... **$info always is Empty**. Why???

Really I don't understand what is happening?
Some ideas?
Help me please!

PD. If I use single CURL or curl_multi_exec (MULTI-CURL with array of URLs goes bad always with the page propiedades.com .. in my LOCAL XAMP Server returns HTML Content... in my Remote Server return NOTHING).

Comment: I tried your code on the url above in your question and `$info` was not empty. Are you meaning when you run that code on the server that is hosting it then `$info` returns empty?

Comment: Yeah! In my Local host has value.... in Remote Server.... i print $info is Empty, really I dont understand... after I use this code to read info with DOM and this info is empty

Comment: Try doing `$uri = "http://localhost:80"`, or `$uri = "https://localhost:8080"`, does that work?

Comment: use URL without HTTPS. like 
http://propiedades.com/alvaro-obregon-df/departamentos-renta

Comment: CURL my own page? I use another pages: inmuebles24.com with curling and goes well In LocalHost and Remote Server... only propiedades.com goes bad in Remote Server. Why I try to do Crawl with my localhost? Where in my localhost?

Comment: By `localhost` I mean on the remote machine, which has your website. Modify the PHP there to have `localhost` as the `$uri` and see if it works.

Comment: cURL is probably disabled either by your host or by `PHP`

Comment: I tried... URL without HTTPS... but also gives Empty result with info content (I see in my logs)...
     ERROR - 2018-06-15 14:36:59 --> OK CRAWLING URI:http://propiedades.com/alvaro-obregon-df/departamentos-renta
ERROR - 2018-06-15 14:36:59 --> 
ERROR - 2018-06-15 14:36:59 -->

Comment: I tried another page like https://inmuebles.metroscubicos.com/casas/venta/distrito-federal/alvaro-obregon/florida/#origin=search&as_word=true  and in LocalHost and Remote Server always gives me HTML Content

Comment: You can try looking at `curl_error($ch)` to check errors.  Also `var_dump($info)` to see if it's empty or if it's boolean false (indicating curl_exec failed).

Comment: Ok! I will try.. curl_error and var_dump

Comment: ERROR - 2018-06-15 14:49:25 --> Curl http://propiedades.com/alvaro-obregon-df/departamentos-renta?pagina=2- error: The requested URL returned error: 405 Not Allowed

Comment: What's meaning 405 error?

Comment: Why in localhost goes Well? and in Remote Server goes bad? Somebody can explain me this error?